# Relaunch an interval into a .click(function() after i clear it in this same function [JQuery]

Tags: jquery, slider, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm doing some slider in JQuery.

So, im starting with an interval calling a transition and clear it when someone click on the "next" button.
Cause if he click it just before the end of the interval he will not have the time to read my slider...
But i want this interval reinitialising just after the click to continue my slideshow if he didnt do anithing else.

I've tried to put it just after the translate function in my .click function but that do some strange things...
My timing isn't right after the click. It's like the two interval are running in the same time or somthing like this.

Anyone can say to me the most elegant method to "relaunch" it after the click transition ?

Here is the code for now: (without the second launch of interval)

```
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();  



jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('.highlight_container').css('x','0');
});



// Animation Loop

jq(document).ready(function() {
    var checkClick = setInterval(function(){
        if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '-2100px'){
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
            x: '0px',
            duration: '750',
            easing: 'in-out',
            });
        }
        else {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
            x: '-=700px',
            duration: '500',
            easing: 'out',          
            });
        }
    }, 5000);

// Next Button  

    jq('.highlight_next').click(function() {
        clearInterval(checkClick);
        if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '-2100px') {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '+=2100px',
                duration: '750',
                easing: 'in-out',
            });
        }   
        else {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '-=700px',
                duration: '500',
                easing: 'out',
            }); 
        }
    });

// Prev Button      

    jq('.highlight_prev').click(function() {
        clearInterval(checkClick);      
        if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '0px') {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '-=2100px',
                duration: '750',
                easing: 'in-out',
            });
        }   
        else {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '+=700px',
                duration: '500',
                easing: 'out',
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any awnser :]

EDIT:

Simply add the setinterval() function at the end of my clik function seems to work. But thats pretty ugly.

```
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();  



jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('.highlight_container').css('x','0');
});



// Animation Loop

jq(document).ready(function() {
    var checkClick = setInterval(function(){
        if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '-2100px'){
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
            x: '0px',
            duration: '750',
            easing: 'in-out',
            });
        }
        else {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
            x: '-=700px',
            duration: '500',
            easing: 'out',          
            });
        }
    }, 5000);

// Next Button  

    jq('.highlight_next').click(function() {
        clearInterval(checkClick);
        if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '-2100px') {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '+=2100px',
                duration: '750',
                easing: 'in-out',
            });
        }   
        else {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '-=700px',
                duration: '500',
                easing: 'out',
            }); 
        }
        checkClick = setInterval(function(){
            if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '-2100px'){
                jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '0px',
                duration: '750',
                easing: 'in-out',
                });
            }
            else {
                jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '-=700px',
                duration: '500',
                easing: 'out',          
                });
            }
        }, 5000);
    });

// Prev Button      

    jq('.highlight_prev').click(function() {
        clearInterval(checkClick);      
        if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '0px') {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '-=2100px',
                duration: '750',
                easing: 'in-out',
            });
        }   
        else {
            jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '+=700px',
                duration: '500',
                easing: 'out',
            }); 
        }
        checkClick = setInterval(function(){
            if (jq('.highlight_container').css('x') === '-2100px'){
                jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '0px',
                duration: '750',
                easing: 'in-out',
                });
            }
            else {
                jq('.highlight_container').transition({
                x: '-=700px',
                duration: '500',
                easing: 'out',          
                });
            }
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Is there a way to call again this same function without 20 lines of code ?

Comment: What is the `.transition()` method? a plugin?

Comment: It's a plugin for JQuery who almost do the same thing than an .animate() function. The good point of this plugin is that it take relative values. You can say put +100 on this param...
More info about it here:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/